# High cpu usage in sleep mode

Tags: suspend, cpu, hibernate, fan, fancontrol

[CPU history in sleep mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Cfw.png)

when I put my laptop (dell inspiron 5401) into sleep mode, as you can see the cpu activity in a few minutes of sleep mode, and fan is turning in full speed.

This problem occurs in both ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10 LTSC.

I don't think that it is a problem but let me say, since I don't have sleep button I added  a shortcut to f9 that puts pc into sleep mode. I deleted that shortcut but problem still continues.

Comment: If the issue occurs with two very different OSes, that would point to a hardware-specific issue. Have you updated the notebook’s firmware? 

Comment: I have updated bios. I am using this pc for about a year.  When I choose cpu on nvidia x server, I barely hear fan sound and not much battery drains. Now it is selected NVIDIA(performance mode), yesterday I put my laptop in sleep mode at 100% battery in the morning it was 75%.

Answer (score 0):

I solved battery drain problem on ubuntu(not yet on windows).

When I LOCK SCREEN (by clicking lock symbol on top bar), problem continues.
I created a shortcut on settings that puts PC into SLEEP MODE.

Use the process:

> Settings → Search shortcuts → Add shortcut(at bottom) → Command: `systemctl suspend`

and add whatever key is empty in your keyboard.
Done.